# intersectionObserver - I would my slide stop to move when an option box reaches one of boundary-side of the container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition, intersection-observer

I'm trying to build an intersection observer allowing my UI to stop a slide transition when the first or last box of included in a container option to reach the boundaries of the container. Hence, the slide is always filled with the box options and it allows a smooth experience from left to right.

A sandbox could be useful, so [here my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1or8rrx1lj)

Some schemas could also be handy, so here: 
  [image]

But as you will see it doesn't stop smoothly, however I have effectively set my observer to make it stop as I describe in the schema,

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: I've taken a look at your sandbox, and i cannot understand why you would go about this by listening for a specifc state in the middle of an animation and interrupting it if you could calculate how far to scroll the container beforehand. (unless i am understanding this completely wrong) (if i read this right, but i am still wrong, please do tell why this would be the way to do this)

Comment: @TimothyGroote thanks for your answer, the core idea is I would allow to dynamically add new slide's element via a CMS, so the code needs to automatically grab my slide's boundaries, that was the core requirement, hope I have answered to you question –

Comment: I would go about it by calculating how far to scroll beforehand (find the last visible item in your slider and use the position of that to scroll right; and find the position of the menu item nearest to the current offset position minus the width of your slide to scroll left) ; that way you don't need complex event or observer systems, but you do get to keep your dynamic menu ;)

Comment: thanks for this very interesting hint, I will get a shot on it